# Twitter API 1.1 : search api

Tags: android, twitter

I want to use twitter API to retrieve tweets with the hashtag in my android mobile application, but it requires authentication
Is there a way to do it without authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to screen scrape. Send an AJAX request like this https://twitter.com/search?q=%23yourhashtag and use [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) to get what you want from the page

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to do it without authentication beyond screen scraping (with violates Twitter's terms of use). However, you can acquire authentication fairly easily by applying to be Twitter developer and submitting an application request. The search feature in Twitter is generally not rate limited so you shouldn't have to do too much work in getting it up and running.